# Deploy ASP.NET Core to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, must include a file with a '.runtimeconfig.json' suffix error

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy ASP.NET Core (dotnet version 5.0) to AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Bitbucket pipelines, but the deploy step results in error: *Instance deployment: Your source bundle has a single .NET Core application. You must include a file with a '.runtimeconfig.json' suffix. The deployment failed.*

Elastic Beanstalk settings:

- Platform: .NET Core on Linux
- Platform branch: .NET Core running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2
- Platform version: 2.1.0 (Recommended)

(changing sensitive data with *#some_text*)

Elastic Beanstalk logs:

```
2020-12-04 02:04:16 UTC+0100 ERROR During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version.
2020-12-04 02:04:16 UTC+0100 ERROR Failed to deploy application.
2020-12-04 02:04:16 UTC+0100 ERROR Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) '#id'. Aborting the operation.
2020-12-04 02:04:16 UTC+0100 INFO  Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2020-12-04 02:04:16 UTC+0100 ERROR [Instance: #id] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error..
2020-12-04 02:04:13 UTC+0100 ERROR Instance deployment: Your source bundle has a single .NET Core application. You must include a file with a '.runtimeconfig.json' suffix. The deployment failed.
2020-12-04 02:04:13 UTC+0100 INFO  Instance deployment found a runtime-dependent .NET Core application in your source bundle.
2020-12-04 02:04:13 UTC+0100 ERROR Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.
2020-12-04 02:04:10 UTC+0100 INFO  Deploying new version to instance(s).
```

eb-engine.log:

```
2020/12/04 01:04:13.566295 [INFO] Executing instruction: StageApplication
2020/12/04 01:04:13.569996 [INFO] extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/
2020/12/04 01:04:13.570035 [INFO] Running command /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/unzip -q -o /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle -d /var/app/staging/
2020/12/04 01:04:13.688429 [INFO] finished extracting /opt/elasticbeanstalk/deployment/app_source_bundle to /var/app/staging/ successfully
2020/12/04 01:04:13.689890 [INFO] Executing instruction: RunAppDeployPreBuildHooks
2020/12/04 01:04:13.689914 [INFO] The dir .platform/hooks/prebuild/ does not exist in the application. Skipping this step...
2020/12/04 01:04:13.689920 [INFO] Executing instruction: CheckProcfileForDotNetCoreApplication
2020/12/04 01:04:13.689925 [INFO] checking application and updating executable file permissions...
2020/12/04 01:04:13.690272 [INFO] found runtime-dependent application...
2020/12/04 01:04:13.690294 [INFO] checking Procfile...
2020/12/04 01:04:13.690317 [ERROR] An error occurred during execution of command [app-deploy] - [CheckProcfileForDotNetCoreApplication]. Stop running the command. Error: there is no .runtimeconfig.json file for your single application. Please provide a valid application
```

Bitbucket pipeline:
*(Shortened - just relevant steps)*

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

pipelines:
    test:
      - step:
          name: "Create release of Api project"
          script:
            - export API_PROJ=path/to/my/project.csproj
            - export CONFIG=Release
            - dotnet publish -c $CONFIG $API_PROJ -o api
          artifacts:
            - api/**
      - step:
          name: "Zip"
          image: atlassian/default-image:2
          script:
            - zip api.zip api/*
          artifacts:
            - api.zip
        - step:
          name: "Deploy to Elastic Beanstalk"
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-elasticbeanstalk-deploy:0.6.7
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                DB_CONNECTION_STRING: $DB_CONNECTION_STRING
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: "eu-west-2"
                APPLICATION_NAME: "#the_app"
                ENVIRONMENT_NAME: $BITBUCKET_BRANCH
                ZIP_FILE: "api.zip"
                S3_BUCKET: '#S3_BUCKET'
```

From the logs it looks like AWS can't find file with suffix '.runtimeconfig.json', but it is in the zip file:
[application release build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSvSU.png) *(directory print screen)*

So far I have tried deploying the application from Bitbucket pipelines and my laptop. I have even tried deploying self contained build, but that resolved in the same error. One of my colleagues succeeded by deploying it with Visual Studio Elastic Beanstalk deploy tool, but that does not solves our problem, it is just temporary fix. I have tried adding Procfile, but that had no effect.

Is there any config for the Elastic Beanstalk I haven't found yet? Any ideas and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because of EB look for `runtimeconfig.json` on root directory. If you extract your zip, You will have the directory structure like this -

```
randomName.zip > random name created by EB
  api
    -runtimeconfig.json
    -
```

While it should look like

```
{randomName.zip} > random name created by EB
  -runtimeconfig.json
```

So changing your buildspec artifacts to `api/**` to `./**` should work. Here is my working example on Github - https://gist.github.com/vickyrathee/06df1416d8bc5f2543c56e4d3b912e96

Comment: So this tutorial is wrong then - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-core-tutorial.html interesting

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to make it work the 'pipe' way, but I have used the [dotnet eb tool](https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli). The pipeline looks like this now:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0

pipelines:
    test:
      - step:
          name: "Create a release of Api project"
          script:
            - export API_PROJ=path/to/my/project.csproj
            - export CONFIG=Release
            - dotnet publish -c $CONFIG $API_PROJ -o api
          artifacts:
            - api/**
      - step:
          name: "Deploy"
          script:
            - apt update
            - apt install -y zip
            - dotnet tool install -g Amazon.ElasticBeanstalk.Tools
            - export PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
            - dotnet eb deploy-environment
              --aws-access-key-id $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
              --aws-secret-key $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
              -pl path/to/my/
              -f net5.0
              --region eu-west-2
              -app #the_app
              -env $BITBUCKET_BRANCH
              --solution-stack '64bit Amazon Linux 2 v2.1.0 running .NET Core'
              --instance-profile #my_role
              --instance-type t2.micro
```

Answer (score 1):

If it helps anyone coming here, apparently the [AWS Deployment Tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/dotnet-linux-core-tutorial.html) is out of date. All you need to do is upload your `site.zip` file (essentially the zipped up output of `dotnet publish`) to EB and it will run. I did not need the outer wrapper with a deployment manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I am on Dotnet 6 and using Github actions. I just got my own pipeline up and running. The problem for me was that my script was Zipping the folder and not only the contents. Eg:

ZIP:

- Deployment (Folder)

  - api.dll (file)
  - settings.json (file)
  - Etc.....

But EB was exspecting just a zip with the files and no root folder. EG:

ZIP:

- api.dll (file)
- settings.json (file)
- Etc.....

Reason being that EB supports deploying multiple apps at the same time. But then you need to add Config files for how each app is run etc. But when you just have a simple deployment for 1 app, you can just give the content and it will start.

My Github action ended up looking like this:

```
name: API
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
  push:
    branches:
    - master
    paths:
    - 'src/Api/**'
env:
  WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: ./publish
  CONFIGURATION: Release
  DOTNET_CORE_VERSION: 6.0.x
  WORKING_DIRECTORY: ./src/Api
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_CORE_VERSION }}
    - name: Restore
      run: dotnet restore "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}"
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-restore
    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --no-build
    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish "${{ env.WORKING_DIRECTORY }}" --configuration ${{ env.CONFIGURATION }} --no-build --output "${{ env.WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}"
    - name: Generate deployment package
      run: cd ${{ env.WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH }}; zip -r ../deployment.zip .; cd ..
    - name: Deploy to EB
      uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v21
      with:
        aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_KEY }}
        application_name: SlideshowbobApi
        environment_name: SlideshowbobApi-dev
        version_label: 1.0.0.${{ github.run_number }}
        region: eu-north-1
        deployment_package: deployment.zip
```

This should be easy to change whatever your build process / testing process looks like.