# Your source bundle has a single .NET Core application. You must include a file with a '.runtimeconfig.json' suffix

Tags: .net, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions

I am trying to deploy app into AWS EBS through GitHub actions.
I am facing the subjected error:

> Instance deployment: Your source bundle has a single .NET Core application. You must include a file with a '.runtimeconfig.json' suffix. The deployment failed.

My YML file looks like:

```yaml
name: publish to EBS
on: 
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      version:
        description: Master Bump Version
        default: v1.0.0
        required: true

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup .NET SDK
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: '7.0.x'

    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore

    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore

    - name: Test
      run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal

    - name: Publish
      run: dotnet publish -c Release -o publish
      
    - name: Build deployment package
      run: zip -r publish.zip publish
      
    - name: Deploy to AWS Elastic Beanstalk
      uses: einaregilsson/beanstalk-deploy@v16
      with:
        aws_access_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
        aws_secret_key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
        region: us-east-1
        application_name: solardev
        environment_name: artifact-dev
        version_label: ${{ github.sha }}
        deployment_package: publish.zip
```

The S3 published folder looks like:

[image: folder]

I tried copying the runtime config JSON files but no success.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploy ASP.NET Core to AWS Elastic Beanstalk, must include a file with a '.runtimeconfig.json' suffix error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65172466/deploy-asp-net-core-to-aws-elastic-beanstalk-must-include-a-file-with-a-runti)

Comment: @Azeem it didn't. I was unable to copy the manifest tile to the guid based zip file.

Comment: Does that `publish` directory contain a `.runtimeconfig.json`?

Comment: yes it has the file with the desired extension

Comment: When it's extract, does it have directory layout as mentioned in the above thread? Please include that in your question.

Comment: bebf786255f9ed0fdf6b921d49932b5b07e774cd - artifact file
  => publish folder
      => all files and runtimeconfig as well

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lVsEp.png

Comment: The above image is the same what you have in your question. You may add `ls -l publish/.runtimeconfig.json` in a `run`. Also, include your complete GHA workflow logs of the deployment step in your question. Those might be helpful.